# Shorthand if/else statements : foo?foo:bar vs foo || bar

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shorthand, shorthand-if

**I wonder how this two are different ?**

```
var hello = foo?foo:bar;
```

vs

```
var hello = foo || bar;
```

Can you explain this ? and some case example ? or both are same ?

PS : foo/bar should be all like string / int / obj / boolean...

Comment: all possible, booleand.. string.. int.. obj.. @JonathonReinhart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `? :` is called the *conditional operator* It takes three arguments (which is why it's sometimes called the "ternary" operator): Something to test, something to return if the test is truthy, and something to return if the test is falsey.*

The second is JavaScript's [curiously-powerful logical OR operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html). It accepts two arguments. It evaluates the first operand and, if that's truthy, returns it; if the first is falsey, it evaluates and returns the second operand.

So the difference between those two is this: With the conditional operator, `foo` may be evaluated twice (if it's truthy). With the `||`, `foo` is only evaluated once. It doesn't really matter if `foo` and `bar` are just simple variable references, but consider:

```
var hello = foo() ? foo() : bar();
// vs
var hello = foo() || bar();
```

You can see how it matters how many times `foo()` is evaluated, if it does any significant work or has any [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

---

(* So what are "truthy" and "falsey" values? The "falsey" values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course `false`. Everything else is "truthy".)